# Rock Paper Scissor game on a Java Server and Client class

Tags: java, class, sockets, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

Hello I am fairly new to Java and I am trying to make a game of Rock, Paper, Scissor where the player can play with the computer. I have two classes Server1 and Client1 and I am trying to create a Rock Paper Scissor game. The Player gives input and the computer generates a random input using the java.util.Random and then that integer is converted into a string and passed to the string variable inputPlayer_2,  which is then compared with the input taken from the player stored in the string variable inputPlayer_1, and a winner is determined according to the logic. I can't seem to figure out why the game won't show the result.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Server1 
{
    private static ServerSocket server = null;
    private static Socket socket = null;
    private static final int port = 8081;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String varPlayer_1 = "";
        String varPlayer_2 = "";
        String inputPlayer_1;
        String inputPlayer_2;
        
        //Generating random values
                Random rand = new Random();
                int upperbound = 3;
                int random = rand.nextInt(upperbound);
        
        //Create IO Objects
        BufferedReader in = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        Scanner consoleInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //Start Server
        try 
        {
            System.out.println("Server is starting ...");
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            System.out.println("Server has started");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Can not listen to port: " + port);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        while(true) {
            
            //Create Socket
            try 
            {
                socket = server.accept();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.out.println("Communication Error with network");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            try 
            {
                in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),true);
                //start1
                out.println("Rock = 0, Paper = 1, scissor = 2");
                
                System.out.println("Player chose " + in.readLine());
                System.out.println("Computer chose: " + random);
                
                inputPlayer_2=String.valueOf(random);
                inputPlayer_1 = in.readLine();
                
                
                if (inputPlayer_1.equals(inputPlayer_2)) {
                    out.println("It's a draw.");
                }
                
                else if (inputPlayer_1.equals("0") && inputPlayer_2.equals("2")) {
                    out.println("Player wins.");
                }
                
                else if (inputPlayer_1.equals("2") && inputPlayer_2.equals("0")) {
                    out.println("Computer wins.");
                }
                
                else if (inputPlayer_1.equals("0") && inputPlayer_2.equals("1")) {
                    out.println("Computer wins.");
                }
                
                else if (inputPlayer_1.equals("1") && inputPlayer_2.equals("0")) {
                    out.println("Player wins.");
                }
                
                else if (inputPlayer_1.equals("2") && inputPlayer_2.equals("1")) {
                    out.println("Player wins.");
                }
                
                else if (inputPlayer_1.equals("1") && inputPlayer_2.equals("2")) {
                    out.println("Computer wins.");
                }
                
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.out.print("Player Left");
                consoleInput.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Client1 {
    public static Socket socket = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    
        String response;
        try 
        {
            socket = new Socket("localhost", 8081);
            System.out.println("Connected to Server\n" + "Socket: " + socket.getInetAddress() + ":" + socket.getPort() + "\n" );
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
            {
                System.out.print("Connection to network can not be established");
            }
        
        BufferedReader in = null;
        PrintWriter out = null;
        Scanner consoleInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        try 
        {
            in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream() ));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            //start0
            System.out.println("Rules: " + in.readLine());
            System.out.print("Choose any: ");
            out.println(consoleInput.nextLine());
            
            // Catch responses
            response = in.readLine();

            // Display responses
            System.out.println("Winner " + response);
            
            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You also have a Main class, right?

Comment: No, I don't. According to the tutorial, I followed I didn't have to. It runs on the console and takes input but it won't show the result.

Comment: How are you running the program? Can you share the tutorial with us? And what type of output are you expecting that you're not getting, printouts?

Comment: I created two packages, client and server. Then moved on to create classes for each named client1 and server1. After writing the code I went to: "RUN AS JAVA APPLICATION" and hence ran the project. Both the server and client communicates with each other at first but after running the logic I am expecting an output of who won the game, which it fails to show.

Comment: Can you share what was printed so we can see how far the program made it? Also, does it end cleanly, crash or just keep running?

Comment: Server is starting...  | 
Server has started   |

Connected to Server   |
Socket: localhost/127.0.0.1:8081   |

Rules: Rock = 0, Paper = 1, scissor = 2   |
Choose any: 1  | 

Player chose 1   |
Computer chose: 1   |
 
After this the program doesn't take any more input, it just keeps running.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in your server class here:

```
System.out.println("Player chose " + in.readLine());
...

inputPlayer_1 = in.readLine();
```

You cannot read the same value from `in` twice. Once the server has read the value to print it, `in` goes back to waiting for more responses from the client, which of course never arrive, because client is done sending. Meanwhile, client is waiting for server, so no one does anything, creating a [deadlock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/deadlock.html).
So you need to save the value read from `in` locally instead and use that:

```
String valueFromServer = in.readLine();
System.out.println("Rules: " + valueFromServer);
....
// Catch responses
inputPlayer_1 = valueFromServer;
```